# Using bash to read/write bytes in a binary file in Linux and Mac OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, binary, hex

In Bash, you are limited from manipulating data in binary files easily, because you can't store ASCII character 0 in a Bash variable. This makes it hard to write or read arbitrary bytes to or from a file.

Also, it would be nice to be able to convert between characters, decimal, hex, and binary on either Linux or OS X/BSD without needing to format and parse the output of programs like hexdump, which may not be consistent or even available across platforms.

Does there exist a Linux and OS X compatible library of routines for Bash to make working with binary data and converting between bases easier?

(Note: this is a self-answered question, but by all means please offer better answers than I've come up with if you have them.)

Comment: Why do you say that a variable can't hold a trailing line-feed? Look: `var=$'\x10'; declare -p var`. It works.

Comment: Yes, that was an error, will edit. The issue is that if you don't set IFS='', and you attempt to echo or printf $var with a trailing LF, the trailing LF is dropped. But that has nothing to do with variables. Also, in your example, I think you meant var=$'\x0A'.

Comment: Yes, I meant `var=$'\x0A'`. Regarding the `echo` issue, there's no problem if you use quotes: `var=$'\x0A'; echo "$var"`. No need to fiddle with `IFS`.

Comment: Well, I'll be damned. You are correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does, because I wrote one. This library of Bash functions ease direct byte manipulations within a file, rather rather than having to represent an entire file in a another format like hex in order to work with it.

Any or all of the following functions can be placed at the top of any Bash script, or loaded via 'source' within a Bash script. They have been tested on Debian Linux and OS X. Note that they can be slimmed down considerably if you want to dispense with the argument validation.

I hope you find these routines helpful; while they might not do exactly what what you need in your script, they can hopefully be starting points or building blocks for what you do need. (I also recognize that languages like Python or Perl might make similar tasks easier, but this solution sticks to Bash and external commands.)

**decToHex:** converts single-byte decimal value to hexadecimal equivalent
**hexToDec:** converts single-byte hexadecimal value to decimal equivalent
**hexToBin:** converts single-byte hexadecimal value to binary string
**binToDec:** converts single-byte binary string value to decimal
**binToHex:** converts single-byte binary string value to hex
**charToDec:** converts single character to corresponding decimal value
**charToHex:** converts single character to corresponding hexadecimal value
**decToChar:** converts single-byte decimal value to corresponding character
**hexToChar:** converts single-byte hexadecimal value to corresponding character
**readchars:** read one or more characters (bytes) from a file
**readcharDec:** read one character from file and convert to corresponding decimal value
**readcharHex:** read one character from file and convert to corresponding hex value
**writechars:** write one or more characters (bytes) to file
**writecharDec:** write corresponding character of single-byte decimal value into file
**writecharHex:** write corresponding character of single-byte hex value into file
**writecharsHex:** write corresponding characters of hex string into file

```
# BashByter functions for working with 8-bit data in Bash

decToHex () {
# converts single-byte decimal value to hexadecimal equivalent
# arg: decimal value from 0-255
# out: two-digit hex value from 00-FF
#exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg, 21=invalid arg
    [[ $1 ]] || return 11
    [[ $2 ]] && return 8
    [[ ( $(printf %d "$1" 2> /dev/null) == $1 ) \
     && ( $1 -ge 0 ) && ( $1 -le 255 ) ]] || return 21
    # args are valid
    printf %02X "$1"
}

hexToDec () {
# converts single-byte hexadecimal value to decimal equivalent
# arg: two-digit hex value from 00-FF
# out: decimal value
#exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg, 21=invalid arg
    [[ $1 ]] || return 11
    [[ $2 ]] && return 8
    [[ ${#1} -eq 2 ]] || return 21
    [[ $(printf %02X "0x$1" 2> /dev/null) == \
     $(echo -n "$1" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]) ]] || return 21
    # args are valid
    printf %d "0x$1"
}

hexToBin () {
# converts single-byte hexadecimal value to binary string
# arg: two-digit hex value from 00-FF
# out: binary string value
#exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg, 21=invalid arg
    [[ $1 ]] || return 11
    [[ $2 ]] && return 8
    [[ ${#1} -eq 2 ]] || return 21
    [[ $(printf %02X "0x$1" 2> /dev/null) == \
     $(echo -n "$1" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]) ]] || return 21
    # args are valid
    for n in 0 1; do
          if [[ ${1:n:1} == "0" ]]; then b="0000"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "1" ]]; then b="0001"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "2" ]]; then b="0010"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "3" ]]; then b="0011"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "4" ]]; then b="0100"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "5" ]]; then b="0101"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "6" ]]; then b="0110"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "7" ]]; then b="0111"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "8" ]]; then b="1000"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "9" ]]; then b="1001"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "A" ]]; then b="1010"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "B" ]]; then b="1011"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "C" ]]; then b="1100"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "D" ]]; then b="1101"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "E" ]]; then b="1110"
        elif [[ ${1:n:1} == "F" ]]; then b="1111"
        fi
        echo -n $b
    done
}

binToDec () {
# converts single-byte binary string (8 bits) value to decimal
# arg: binary string (each char is 0 or 1) up to 8 bits
# out: decimal value
#exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg, 21=invalid arg
    [[ $1 ]] || return 11
    [[ $2 ]] && return 8
    dec=0
    bits=$1
    while (( ${#bits} < 8 )); do
        bits="0$bits"
    done
    for n in {0..7}; do
        [[ ${bits:$n:1} == "0" || ${bits:$n:1} == "1" ]] || return 21
        (( dec+=( ${bits:$n:1} * ( 2**(7-$n) ) ) ))
    done
    echo -n $dec
}

binToHex () {
# converts single-byte binary string (8 bits) value to hex
# arg: binary string (each char is 0 or 1) up to 8 bits
# out: hex value
#exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg, 21=invalid arg
    [[ $1 ]] || return 11
    [[ $2 ]] && return 8
    dec=0
    bits=$1
    while (( ${#bits} < 8 )); do
        bits="0$bits"
    done
    for n in {0..7}; do
        [[ ${bits:$n:1} == "0" || ${bits:$n:1} == "1" ]] || return 21
        (( dec+=( ${bits:$n:1} * ( 2**(7-$n) ) ) ))
    done
    printf %02X $dec
}

charToDec () {
# converts single character to corresponding decimal value
# stdin OR arg: one character
#  [arg overrides stdin; stdin is required for NUL (0) or LF (0x0A)]
# out: decimal value from 0-255
#exit: 8=extraneous arg, 9=invalid stdin,
#      11=missing stdin/arg, 21=invalid arg
    [[ ( ! -t 0 ) && $1 ]] && { cat > /dev/null; return 8; }
    [[ ( -t 0 ) ]] && { [[ $2 ]] && return 8; [[ $1 ]] || return 11; }
    # arg/stdin is potentially valid (additional check below)
    charX="$1X"; [[ $1 ]] || charX="$(cat; echo -n 'X';)"
    [[ ${#charX} -le 2 ]] || return $(( $([[ $1 ]]; echo $?) ? 9 : 21 ))
    # above line verifies that arg/stdin is valid
    [[ ${#charX} -ne 2 ]] && { echo -n 0; return 0; }
    echo -n "${charX:0:1}" | od -t u1 | \
     head -1 | sed 's/[0\ ]*//' | tr -d ' \n'
}

charToHex () {
# converts single character to corresponding hexadecimal value
# stdin OR arg: one character
#  [arg overrides stdin; stdin is required for NUL (0) or LF (0x0A)]
# out: decimal value from 0-255
#exit: 8=extraneous arg, 9=invalid stdin,
#      11=missing stdin/arg, 21=invalid arg
    [[ ( ! -t 0 ) && $1 ]] && { cat > /dev/null; return 8; }
    [[ ( -t 0 ) ]] && { [[ $2 ]] && return 8; [[ $1 ]] || return 11; }
    # arg/stdin is potentially valid (additional check below)
    charX="$1X"; [[ $1 ]] || charX="$(cat; echo -n 'X';)"
    [[ ${#charX} -le 2 ]] || return $(( $([[ $1 ]]; echo $?) ? 9 : 21 ))
    # above line verifies that stdin/arg is valid
    [[ ${#charX} -ne 2 ]] && { echo -n "00"; return 0; }
    printf %02X $(echo -n "${charX:0:1}" | od -t u1 | \
     head -1 | sed 's/[0\ ]*//' | tr -d ' \n')
}

decToChar () {
# converts single-byte decimal value to equivalent character
# arg: decimal number from 0-255
# out: one character
#exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg, 21=invalid arg
    [[ $1 ]] || return 11
    [[ $2 ]] && return 8
    [[ ( $(printf %d "$1" 2> /dev/null ) == $1 ) \
     && ( $1 -ge 0 ) && ( $1 -le 255 ) ]] || return 21
    # args are valid
    echo -n -e "\x$(printf %02X "$1")"
}

hexToChar () {
# converts single-byte hexadecimal value to corresponding character
# arg: two-digit hexadecimal number from 00-FF
# out: one character
#exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg, 21=invalid arg
    [[ $1 ]] || return 11
    [[ $2 ]] && return 8
    [[ ${#1} -eq 2 ]] || return 21
    [[ $(printf %02X "0x$1" 2> /dev/null) == \
     $(echo -n "$1" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]) ]] || return 21
    # args are valid
    echo -n -e "\x$1"
}

readchars () {
# read one or more characters from a file
# arg1: filename
# arg2: (optional) offset (# of bytes to skip before reading)
# arg3: (optional) # of chars to read (default is until end of file)
#  out: sequence of characters
# exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg1,
#       21=invalid arg1, 22=invalid arg2, 23=invalid arg3
    [[ $1 ]] || return 11
    [[ $4 ]] && return 8
    [[ -f $1 ]] || return 21
    [[ $2 ]] && { [[ ( $(printf %d "$2" 2> /dev/null) == $2 ) \
     && ( $2 -ge 0 ) ]] || return 22; }
    [[ $3 ]] && { [[ ( $(printf %d "$3" 2> /dev/null) == $3 ) \
     && ( $3 -ge 0 ) ]] || return 23; }
    # args are valid
    dd if="$1" bs=1 skip=$(($2)) $([[ $3 ]] && echo -n "count=$3") \
     2> /dev/null
}

readcharDec () {
# read one character from file & convert to equivalent decimal value
# arg1: filename
# arg2: (optional) offset (# of bytes to skip before reading)
#  out: decimal value from 0-255
# exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg1,
#       21=invalid arg1, 22=invalid arg2
    [[ $1 ]] || return 11
    [[ $3 ]] && return 8
    [[ -f $1 ]] || return 21
    [[ $2 ]] && { [[ ( $(printf %d "$2" 2> /dev/null) == $2 ) \
     && ( $2 -ge 0 ) ]] || return 22; }
    # args are valid
    charX="$(dd if="$1" bs=1 skip=$(($2)) \
     count=1 2> /dev/null; echo -n X)"
    [[ ${#charX} -gt 1 ]] || { echo -n 0; return 0; }
    echo -n "${charX:0:1}" | od -t u1 | \
     head -1 | sed 's/[0\ ]*//' | tr -d ' \n'
}

readcharHex () {
# read one character from file & convert to corresponding hex value
# arg1: filename
# arg2: (optional) offset (# of bytes to skip before reading)
#  out: two-digit hex value from 00-FF
# exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg1,
#       21=invalid arg1, 22=invalid arg2
    [[ $1 ]] || return 11
    [[ $3 ]] && return 8
    [[ -f $1 ]] || return 21
    [[ $2 ]] && { [[ ( $(printf %d "$2" 2> /dev/null) == $2 ) \
     && ( $2 -ge 0 ) ]] || return 22; }
    # args are valid
    charX="$(dd if="$1" bs=1 skip=$(($2)) \
     count=1 2> /dev/null; echo -n X)"
    [[ ${#charX} -gt 1 ]] || { echo -n "00"; return 0; }
    printf %02X $(echo -n "${charX:0:1}" | od -t u1 | \
     head -1 | sed 's/[0\ ]*//' | tr -d ' \n')
}

writechars () {
# write one or more characters (bytes) to file
# arg1: filename
# arg2: (optional) offset (# of bytes to skip before writing)
# arg3 OR stdin: sequence of characters
#  [stdin required if writing NUL (0) or trailing LF (0x0A) chars]
#  out: nothing
# exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg1,
#       13=missing stdin/arg3, 22=invalid arg2
    [[ $1 ]] || { [[ -t 0 ]] || cat > /dev/null; return 11; }
    [[ $2 ]] && { [[ ( $(printf %d "$2" 2> /dev/null) == $2 ) && \
     ( $2 -ge 0 ) ]] || { [[ -t 0 ]] || cat > /dev/null; return 22; } }
    [[ ( ! -t 0 ) && $3 ]] && { cat > /dev/null; return 8; }
    [[ ( -t 0 ) ]] && { [[ $4 ]] && return 8; [[ $3 ]] || return 13; }
    # args are valid
    if [[ -t 0 ]]; then
        echo -n "$3" | \
         dd of="$1" bs=1 seek=$(($2)) conv=notrunc 2> /dev/null
    else
        dd of="$1" bs=1 seek=$(($2)) conv=notrunc 2> /dev/null
    fi
}

writecharDec () {
# write corresponding character of single-byte decimal value into file
# arg1: filename
# arg2: offset (# of bytes to skip before writing)
# arg3: decimal number from 0-255
# exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg1, 12=missing arg2,
#       13=missing arg3, 22=invalid arg2, 23=invalid arg3
#  out: nothing
    [[ $1 ]] || return 11; [[ $2 ]] || return 12; [[ $3 ]] || return 13
    [[ $4 ]] && return 8
    [[ ( $(printf %d "$2" 2> /dev/null) == $2 ) \
     && ( $2 -ge 0 ) ]] || return 22
    [[ ( $(printf %d "$3" 2> /dev/null) == $3 ) \
     && ( $3 -ge 0 ) && ( $3 -lt 255 ) ]] || return 23
    # args are valid
    echo -n -e "\x$(printf %02X "$3")" | \
     dd of="$1" bs=1 seek=$(($2)) conv=notrunc 2> /dev/null
}

writecharHex () {
# write corresponding character of single-byte hex value into file
# arg1: filename
# arg2: offset (# of bytes to skip before writing)
# arg3: two-digit hexadecimal number from 00-FF
#  out: nothing
# exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg1, 12=missing arg2,
#       13=missing arg3, 22=invalid arg2, 23=invalid arg3
    [[ $1 ]] || return 11; [[ $2 ]] || return 12; [[ $3 ]] || return 13
    [[ $4 ]] && return 8
    [[ ( $(printf %d "$2" 2> /dev/null) == $2 ) \
     && ( $2 -ge 0 ) ]] || return 22
    [[ $(printf %02X "0x$3" 2> /dev/null) == \
     $(echo -n "$3" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]) ]] || return 23
    # args are valid
    echo -n -e "\x$3" | \
     dd of="$1" bs=1 seek=$2 conv=notrunc 2> /dev/null
}

writecharsHex () {
# write corresponding characters of hex values into file
# arg1: filename
# arg2: offset (# of bytes to skip before writing)
# arg3: string of two-digit hexadecimal numbers from 00-FF
#  out: nothing
# exit: 8=extraneous arg, 11=missing arg1, 12=missing arg2,
#       13=missing arg3, 22=invalid arg2, 23=invalid arg3
    [[ $1 ]] || return 11; [[ $2 ]] || return 12; [[ $3 ]] || return 13
    [[ $4 ]] && return 8
    [[ ( $(printf %d "$2" 2> /dev/null) == $2 ) \
    && ( $2 -ge 0 ) ]] || return 22
    p=0
    offset=$2
    len=${#3}
    while (( p < len )); do
        outByte=${3:$p:2}
        [[ $(printf %02X "0x$outByte" 2> /dev/null) == \
        $(echo -n "$outByte" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]) ]] || return 23
        # args are valid
        echo -n -e "\x$outByte" | \
        dd of="$1" bs=1 seek=$offset conv=notrunc 2> /dev/null
        (( p += 2 ))
        (( offset++ ))
    done
}
```

Comment: _but this is an all-Bash solution for those who want it_ I did notice some non-bash commands here and there (`cat`, `tr`, `od`, `dd`, `head`, `sed`); actually some of them could be replaced more elegantly and more efficiently by builtins. But this is not code-review; moreover I'm not sure SO is a place to advertise your products (I might be wrong on this last point).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I'm not sure what product you think I'm advertising; I'm not a professional coder, and these are some routines I wrote for my own projects based on knowledge I'd gleaned from here and elsewhere and figured out myself. I thought they might be useful to others, and this seemed like a logical place to share them, as per http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer . If you can improve them, please do, not for me, but for anyone other visitor who might benefit. Isn't that the point of this site -- to get to the best solutions through collective intelligence and experience?